# Does Windows 8 support MS Office 2007?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, microsoft-office

Does Windows 8 support MS Office 2007 and other software which will run on MS Windows 7?

If any one knows, please let me know.

Comment: any software can be run using compatablity settings of windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this list](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/ProductViewerWithDefaultFilters?TempOsid=Windows%208&Locale=en-us&Architecture=X64&TextSearch=OFFICE%2b2007&Type=Both&CurrentPage=0&TotalPages=1&ShowCriteria=0&SortCriteria=Relevance&Compatibility=Unknown&LastRequested=14) Windows 8(.1) support Office 2007. Make sure you use the Sp3 and all offered updates from WindowsUpdate.